# Android Content Provider tied to external storage (text file)

Tags: android

I'm trying to code a system for running user studies. I have a webpage and a webservice on top of a user DB.
My Android app is a client to run the studies on. I'm use the Account Manager to store user credentials authenticated via the webservice. The point is to then implement a sync adapter that will send a text file with study data to my server, via the webservice (using the credentials).

My problem is that I'm having difficulty with the Content Provider, I've searched a lot throught the web but I can't seem to find an example of how to code a Content Provider tied to a file on external storage. All the examples I find use Content Providers tied to database tables. Can someone please point me in the right direction or shed some coding light? (BTW, I have read the Android Developer texts on Content Providers, also, I'm using Android 2.2).

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers,
André Coelho

Answer (score 0):

A content provider can be used to read file data by overriding the [openFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#openFile%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%29) method. You could have a top level provider that provides an listing of all the files (via query) then each file could have its own unique URI that could then have openFile called on it to retrieve the file data.

Comment: I see. Would it also be possible for to have the content provider write data in the file, as oposed to doing it in an activity like I do now?

Comment: Also, what type of CONTENT_TYPE (cursor) should I use?

Comment: You can write to the file descriptor returned from openFile() see the mode parameter. You can return a content type of null as your provider won't return a cursor.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to reply. :) That piece of information is quite interesting. I guess I'll have to give it a try. I'll get back to you once I manage to advance a bit more.